# How to access to Phantom wallet data?

Tags: reactjs, phantom-wallet

I'am new in Phantom/ Solana universe and I want to create my first web app using Phantom Wallet into my React app. I used the Phantom app documentation to connect to my wallet, that's work.
But now, I want to show in my app some data about the connected wallet like NFT possessed, solana balance and so on.

Does anyone know what should I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have my code for this. And will work fine.
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-phantom-data-ypsq7b)

But remember install @solana/web3.js v1.30.2
If you gone to higher version some extra dependencies and webpack config is needed.

Comment: Thank you Spyder but I can't see any solution to my question. 
I want to display possessed NFt image to user directly in my app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okk sure you can do it.
When you get all NFTs you can see a uri in that and you just need to hit that uri to get all the data including there images.

I will share you a code soon.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Thank you so much Spyder, could you show me a piece of your code please ?
Many thanks for your help !